# Django/Python - Not able to display result in line by line and with filename

Tags: python, django

```
urls.py

from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('VRFFILELIST/',views.sindex,name="Home-Page"),
    ]

forms.py:
==========
from django import forms

class stringform(forms.Form):
    Enter_VRF_Name_To_Search = forms.CharField(max_length=20)

views.py
===========

from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import stringform

import os

def sindex(request):
    search_path = "C:/AUTOMATE/STRING/TESTFILE/"
    file_type = ".txt"
    Sstringform = stringform()
    Scontext = {'Sstringform' : Sstringform}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        SVRFTEXT = Scontext['Enter_VRF_Name_To_Search'] = request.POST['Enter_VRF_Name_To_Search']
        #fname1 = []
        ftext = []
        Scontext['resultlist'] = ftext
        for fname in os.listdir(path=search_path):
            fo = open(search_path + fname)
            fread = fo.readline()
            line_no = 1
            while fread != '':
                fread = fo.readline()
                if SVRFTEXT in fread:
                    ftext.append(fread)
                    line_no +=1
            fo.close()

    return render(request, 'demoapp/VRFFILELIST.html', Scontext)

VRFFILELIST.HTML
===================

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>VRF FILE LIST</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST">
       {% csrf_token %}
       <table>
              {{Sstringform.as_table}}
       </table>
       <button type="submit">Send Command</button>
</form>

       <table>
              <h3>VRF IN LIST OF FILES</h3>
<textarea rows="20" cols="80" name="conf" form="conf" id="conf">{{resultlist}}</textarea>
       </table>
</body>
</body>
</html>
```

Output:

```
[' ip vrf forwarding TEST:VRFA\n', ' ip vrf forwarding TEST:VRFA\n', ' address-family ipv4 vrf TEST:VRFA\n', '  neighbor 10.10.10.1 route-map TEST:VRFA-IN in\n', '  neighbor 10.10.10.1 route-map TEST:VRFA-OUT out\n', ' ip vrf forwarding TEST:VRFA\n', '  neighbor 192.168.10.2 route-map TEST:VRFA-IN in\n', '  neighbor 192.168.10.2 route-map TEST:VRFA-OUT out\n']
```

## Required Output:

## TEST-FILE-A:

ip vrf forwarding TEST:VRFA

ip vrf forwarding TEST:VRFA

address-family ipv4 vrf TEST:VRFA

neighbor 10.10.10.1 route-map TEST:VRFA-IN in

neighbor 10.10.10.1 route-map TEST:VRFA-OUT out

## TEST-FILE-C:

ip vrf forwarding TEST:VRFA

neighbor 192.168.10.2 route-map TEST:VRFA-IN in

neighbor 192.168.10.2 route-map TEST:VRFA-OUT out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this `<textarea rows="20" cols="80" name="conf" form="conf" id="conf">{% for result in resultlist%}{{result}}{% endfor %}</textarea>`

Comment: mentioned code gives me below resut :

resultresultresultresultresultresultresultresult

Comment: Wow ,great it worked thank you. one more help .  i need to display filename as well which contains that string , so what change i need to do in script

Comment: if i m modifying script with : ftext.append(fread + fname) , i m getting output :

 ip vrf forwarding TEST:VRFA
TEST-FILE-A.txt ip vrf forwarding TEST:VRFA
TEST-FILE-A.txt address-family ipv4 vrf TEST:VRFA
TEST-FILE-A.txt  neighbor 10.49.252.241 route-map TEST:VRFA-BT-IN in
TEST-FILE-A.txt  neighbor 10.49.252.241 route-map TEST:VRFA-BT-OUT out
TEST-FILE-A.txt ip vrf forwarding TEST:VRFA
TEST-FILE-C.txt  neighbor 192.168.10.2 route-map TEST:VRFA-IN in
TEST-FILE-C.txt  neighbor 192.168.10.2 route-map TEST:VRFA-OUT out
TEST-FILE-C.txt

but i need filename first , then respective lines

Comment: I recommended you for use dictionary: `ftext.append({'file_name': fname, 'text': fread})`, then your code in template forloop: `{{result.file_name}}{{result.text}}` instead of `{{result}}`

Comment: No luck , Same Result .

TEST-FILE-A.txt ip vrf forwarding TEST:VRFA
TEST-FILE-A.txt ip vrf forwarding TEST:VRFA
TEST-FILE-A.txt address-family ipv4 vrf TEST:VRFA
TEST-FILE-A.txt  neighbor 10.49.252.241 route-map TEST:VRFA-BT-IN in
TEST-FILE-C.txt ip vrf forwarding TEST:VRFA
TEST-FILE-C.txt  neighbor 192.168.10.2 route-map TEST:VRFA-IN in

I think inside for loop fname , first if statement will require for fname and inside while loop require to extract list of contents but how to pass both variable to Scontext['resultlist'] that i m not able to get